# Javascript: Barnsley Fern Fractal

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, fractals

Can someone look over this code and point out why the resulting barnsley fern fractal doesn't look right?

```
function barnsley (ctx) {

ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.translate(ctx.canvas.width/2,ctx.canvas.height/2);
var self = this;

this.itts = 100000;
this.ittsCount = 0;
this.x = 0;
this.y = 0;

this.main = function () {
    for (var i=0;i<itts;i++) {
        var rand = Math.random()*100;
        if (rand < 1) {
            self.one();
        } else if (rand < 86) {
            self.two();
        } else if (rand < 94) {
            self.three();
        } else {
            self.four();
        }
    }
}

this.one = function () {
    var xn = self.x;
    var yn = self.y;
    var zx = 0;
    var zy = 0.16 * yn;
    self.drawPoint(zx,zy);
}

this.two = function () {
    var xn = self.x;
    var yn = self.y;
    var zx = 0.85 * xn + 0.4 * yn;
    var zy = -0.04 * xn + 0.85 * yn + 1.6;
    self.drawPoint(zx,zy);
}

this.three = function () {
    var xn = self.x;
    var yn = self.y;
    var zx = 0.2 * xn - 0.26 * yn;
    var zy = 0.23 * xn + 0.22 * yn + 1.6;
    self.drawPoint(zx,zy);
}

this.four = function () {
    var xn = self.x;
    var yn = self.y;
    var zx = -0.15 * xn + 0.28 * yn;
    var zy = 0.26 * xn + 0.24 * yn + 0.44;
    self.drawPoint(zx,zy);
}

this.drawPoint = function (xn,yn) {
    self.x = xn;
    self.y = yn;
    ctx.fillRect(xn*20,-yn*20,1,1);
}

this.main();
}
```

It has the right general shape but I must be missing something, I've checked the algorithms and such but to no avail.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can ya make a jsfiddle? or what is ctx? :|

Comment: @Ronnie a `<canvas>` context (`ctx` is the typical name for one)

Comment: I don't understand why people are voting to close this as not constructive, this is a well-defined question and does not warrant discussion or subjective answers.

Comment: @Doorknob thanks, I had a feeling it had to do with canvas, but `ctx.canvas` confused me. I thought it'd be `canvas.ctx`. Never played around with it. Seeing Peter's jsfiddle makes sense now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was just a small error while typing the numbers. (I checked against [this source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnsley_fern#Computer_generation), it looks like it uses the same numbers you are using).

In this `this.two` functions, you need to change

```
var zx = 0.85 * xn + 0.4 * yn;
```

to

```
var zx = 0.85 * xn + 0.04 * yn;
```

You can see [this fix in action on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnTfj/3/).

Comment: Thanks very much. Seems like one number out of all of them can make all the difference.

Comment: "one number out of all of them" --- this is the whole point of chaos theory, of which fractals are a part, that the output of some functions is sensitive to the exact input given. For more read James Gleick's chaos book; very approachable.

Answer (score 0):

There are millions of way to do it but I think you might like [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/p49HD/1/) .

Updates/steps are handled by the JS scheduler/timers. It's non-blocking and won't have your CPU go crazy with a heavy for loop.

The fractal data is also handled a different way. You could put any fractal made with affine transforms just by changing the parameters at one place. You also don't have to sum the probabilities as it does it for you.

ex: (StackOverflow won't let me post a JSFiddle link without a code exemple)

```
var probability_transforms =  [
    {
        "probability": 0.01, 
        "item": function(point){ return affine_transform(point, 0, 0, 0, 0.16, 0, 0) }
    },
    {
        "probability": 0.85, 
        "item": function(point){ return affine_transform(point, 0.85, 0.04, -0.04, 0.85, 0, 1.6) }
    },
    {
        "probability": 0.07,
        "item": function(point){ return affine_transform(point, 0.2, -0.26, 0.23, 0.22, 0, 1.6) }
    },
    {
        "probability": 0.07, 
        "item": function(point){ return affine_transform(point, -0.15, 0.28, 0.26, 0.24, 0, 0.44) }
    }
];
```

Have fun :)